# Schedueled command how to correctly get database informartion by using DB query's

Tags: mysql, laravel, select, scheduled-tasks

In this project users can like each other's pictures and at certain times (with a cron job that I haven't made yet) the project should automatically pick a winner ( this will be the picture with the most likes).

I've created a table in my MySQL DB that store's the `post_id` and the `user_id` of the user that liked the post. In a scheduled command, I would like to get the `post_id` that appears the most in the table.

I made a Laravel command `do:newwinner` and in its handle function, 
I first tested the query directly in my DB and it worked it gave me a list of all the posts with the winner on top of the list. Then I tried to implement that query in my command. But when I tried to run it it gives me errors.

This is the handle function in my do:newwinner command

```
public function handle()
{
    echo "start job";
    $outcome = DB::select('select post_id, COUNT(post_id) from post_user group by post_id desc');
    echo " end job".$outcome;
}
```

Also, the import that I used:
    `use Illuminate\Database;`

I want to be able to extract the winner from my database each time so I can store it in a winners table in my DB.

when running:
    `php artisan do:newwinner`
this is the error message I get:

```
    ?[41;1m Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError ?[49;22m : ?[33mClass 'App\Console\Commands\DB' not found?[39m

  at ?[32mD:\School\3de jaar\Development\web-development\CocaCola\app\Console\Commands\newWinner.php?[39m:?[32m44?[39m
    40|      */
    41|     public function handle()
    42|     {
    43|         echo "start job";
  > 44|         $outcome = DB::select('post_id,
COUNT(post_id) from post_user group by post_id desc');
    45|         echo " end job".$outcome;
    46|     }
    47| }
    48|

  ?[33mException trace:?[39m

  ?[36m1   ?[39m?[33mApp\Console\Commands\newWinner::handle()?[39m
      ?[32mD:\School\3de jaar\Development\web-development\CocaCola\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php?[39m:?[32m32?[39m

  ?[36m2   ?[39m?[33mcall_user_func_array([])?[39m
      ?[32mD:\School\3de jaar\Development\web-development\CocaCola\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php?[39m:?[32m32?[39m

  ?[32mPlease use the argument ?[39m?[31m-v?[39m?[32m to see more details.?[39m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DB` is not in your current namespace `App\Console\Commands`. So you can either import it at the top

```
use DB;
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

or precede it with a backslash `\DB::table(...)`. This solves the class not found exception.

Comment: Be aware that DB is an alias and it must be present in your config/app.php file under aliases. The fully qualified namespace is Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB

Comment: Thank you  Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB solved my not found exception , I'm now getting a new error  ```  ?[41;1m ErrorException ?[49;22m : ?[33mArray to string conversion?[39m ``` I think this error comes from my db query?

Comment: Yes because you're doing  `echo " end job".$outcome;` use `print_r($outcome)`. And the `$outcome` is array not string so echo wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I was so focussed on my query that I forgot about that. Everything works fine now thank you for your time.